# Form return by ajax not sending correct id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm returning a form for each row in a table via ajax. I did it so that I can insert records **specific to a student id** on each row. This is how the form looks when it is return by ajax:
[image]

**Problem is** when the form is returned and I tried to insert a score for the first student **Ralph T. Hensley** I get the correct `id` of that student. But when I tried to insert a score for the remaining student I get the `id` for **Ralph T. Hensley** which is `7`

I'm correctly displaying the distinct ids of each student, but it seems like whenever I click the save button it only returns the id of the first student in the result set. Structure of my code is below.

This is how I'm returning my form via ajax.

```
$output .= '<tbody>';
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        # code...
                            // unseen fields values that will be send
                        $output .= '<form action="#" method="post" class="st_score_form">';
                            $output .= '<tr>';
                                $output .= '<td>
                                    <input type="number" class="student_set" name="student_id" value="'.$row['student_id'].'">
                                    </td>';
                                $output .= '<td style="display:none;">
                                    <input type="text" class="subject_set" name="subject" value="'.$subject_id.'">
                                    </td>';
                                $output .= '<td style="display:none;">
                                    <input type="number" class="class_set" name="class_id" value="'.$class_id.'"></td>';
                                $output .= '<td style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="term" value="'.$term.'"></td>';
                                $output .= '<td>'.$row["first_name"]." ".substr($row["middle_name"], 0, 1).". ".$row["surname"].'</td>';
                                $output .= '<td><input type="number" class="score_set" min="59" max="100"  name="score" class="form-control" required="required"></td>';
                                $output .= '<td><input type="submit" name="savebtn" value="Save" class="btn btn-info form-control savebtn"></td>';
                            $output .= '</tr>';
                            // -- end of unseen fields
                        $output .= '</form>';
                    }
        $output .= '</tbody>';
```

This is my script:

```
$(document).on('click', '.savebtn', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var student = $('.student_set').val();
    var student_class = $('.class_set').val();
    var subject = $('.subject_set').val();
    var score = $('.score_set').val();

    console.log("Student " +student);
    console.log("Class " +student_class);
    console.log("subject " +subject);
    console.log("Score " +score);

    if (student != null && student_class != null && subject != null && score != null) {
      $.ajax({
        url:"includes/ajax/create_score.php",
        method:"post",
        data:{"student":student, "class":student_class, "subject":subject, "score":score},
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(data){
          $("#success").fadeIn('slow', function(){       
             $("#success").html('<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i></button><b><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Alert! </b>'+data+'</div>');
           });
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#result").html('');
    }


});
$('body').append('<button class="savebtn"></button>');
```

I'm open to feed backs and suggestions on ways I can make this work. Thanks!!!

Comment: Ids have to be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: you can't use id in loops use class instead of this

Comment: Try not to work with IDs in loop. You should know to give an ID only once to ONE element in HTML. Then when you want to select the right Element, try to select the parent <tr> and search in that <tr> for an input Element with the name student_id -> $(this).parents('tr').first().find('[student_id]').first()

Comment: Id made the changes but that still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Chris can you be more descriptive and explicit on how I can adopt that into my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing it's bad practice to set the same id's for all input , (id must be unique in the whole page )

In your code you are getting the wrong values here `var student = $('.student_set').val();`:

you should get the id as :

```
$(this).parents('tr').find('.student_set').val();
```

also for the other field.

bellow a working snippet :

```js
$(function() {
  $(".savebtn").on("click", function(e) {
    alert($(this).parents('tr').find(".student_set").val());
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <tr>
    <form>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="student_set" name="student_id1" value="1">
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" class="score_set" min="59" max="100" name="score" class="form-control" required="required"></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="savebtn" value="Save" class="btn btn-info form-control savebtn"></td>
    </form>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <form>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="student_set" name="student_id2" value="2">
      </td>
      <td><input type="number" class="score_set" min="59" max="100" name="score" class="form-control" required="required"></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="savebtn" value="Save" class="btn btn-info form-control savebtn"></td>
    </form>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: should I assign that to my variable?

Comment: thanks @bRIMOs got it working. Don't know if you have the time for this but, I added a required attribute to my score input, but when I click save without entering a value into the score field it doesn't validate. Any ideas please?

Comment: Have you added  the form  tag ? otherwise it wont work ! see my updated answer :)

Comment: It submit directly ?

Answer (score 1):

The Scope in your JS Function is the Button. Means the Keyword `this` is the DOM Element of the klicked Button.

Now you can start searching on the DOM ( start point is your button ) for the input field with the `student_id` you are searching for.

```
$(this)
    .parents('tr').first()          // go up the HTML structure to the next TR.
    .find('[name="student_id"]').first()   // find the input with the name `student_id`
```